# Piping ls to less and have real time monitoring of filesystem changes

Tags: linux, bash

How would I make something like the following work in Linux?

```
ls -l | less
```

While in less I hit `F` and now I would like to be able to automatically monitor filesystem changes from the `ls` command?
I understand that this is not the usecase of the above command but what would the closes thing be that can do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `watch` command which by default runs the passed command in shell and update every 2s by default. You can still change the delay.

```
watch -n 0.5 ls -l
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`watch`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/watch) command:

```
watch 'ls -l'
```